# php error checking count users

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I am trying to detect if a username exists already in our database and if so give an error but if not continue with processing in this form. I checked and username is available and the rest of the code works with another check:

```
   $ip_query = $SQL->query("SELECT username FROM myusers WHERE username='". $username . "' LIMIT 1");
   $ip_array = $SQL->fetch_array($ip_query);
   if (count($ip_array)>0) 
   {
      $_SESSION['error'] =="User already exists.";
      header("location: page1_form.php"); //redirecting to first page

   }
   else {
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
         $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;

   }
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the final version, but for now this does not work as expected and the check is not run

Comment: imo: debugging: `var_dump($username);`. `var_dump($ip_query);` and  `var_dump($ip_array);` Does that query with that `$username`  return anything in an 'SQL IDE'. I don't need the results to be displayed here. It is just so that you can check that the query actually works before trying to run it in PHP. I would create the query into a variable and 'var_dump' that so I can check that it is correct. Also, set all PHP error display on!

Comment: Ryan Thank you that helped me see the error and the basic code is working